# Firebase not instal on windows 10

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

fierbase: The name "fierbase" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, as well as the presence and correctness of the path, and then try again.
line: 1 character: 1

- fierbase login
- ```
     + CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (fierbase: String) [], CommandNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException
  ```

PS.
Did everything written in thi instructions on the official website, but still can not install write that I didnt have firebase on my conputer,Nodejs and NPM the latest versions, and I have NPM in my PATH.

Comment: Well, is it `fierbase` or is it `firebase`?

Comment: No in console I write firebase.

Answer (score 0):

As the error you are receiving clearly states, you should verify the spelling of the command you are trying to run. You are misspelling firebase as fierbase.

Comment: Thank you but I try both variant and both didn't work.